# Can't build cordova app on windows 7

Tags: windows, cordova, web-applications

I went through the whole process to initialize a cordova app from the command line as state on [this webpage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html). I added the windows platform with the command `cordova platform add windows`, and then tried to build it. But I got an error saying that I may not have the required environment or OS to build this project. I'm not sure what that means or what I should do, this error isn't described on the webpage I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Windows Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html):

> This guide shows how to set up your SDK development environment to
>   build and deploy Cordova apps for Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows
>   Phone 8.1, and Windows 10 Universal App Platform.

There is no mention of Windows 7 which is what you state in your title. Thus the "Windows Platform" may not be supported on that version of Windows. Imagine trying to build a Windows application in Windows 95 today or Windows 98? You likely wouldn't do it as they are too old which is how some may view Windows 7 today as there are a few newer versions out there to support.